# Pulling a div from 3rd party domain to display on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe, cross-domain, dynamic-data

So here's what I am trying to do:
I run a Veetle.com channel where I broadcast video. Veetle allows you to show the Schedule of programs to be played. I want to strip the information in this div container directly from my Veetle page, and display it on my personal webpage.

Originally I tried injecting CSS into an iframe containing the Veetle page that removed everything except the div containing the schedule. This didn't pan out so well, because apparently this is not allowed using 3rd party domains. This just became a **HUGE** headache.

I can't just chop everything out using inline stylesheet margins, because the audio from the broadcast will still be heard (even though it wouldn't be visable) & that could become very confusing to visitors of my webpage.
To solve this I tried some javascript that removes embedded objects, but I ran into the whole scripting through an iframe on a 3rd party domain problem again.

Anybody got ANY ideas?

Comment: use `php` or `asp` or `jsp` or ..

Answer (score 0):

Try searching Google for "XMLHttpRequest cross domain" or something similar.  I have used XMLHttpRequest locally before and it returns the results in a variable that you can strip everything else out of.  The few sites I glanced at seem to indicate that it will work fine on other domains by sending a just a few extra headers.

Comment: actually im not so sure you need any extra headers (i think i misread some code). just read up on it...

Comment: From what I can understand, a proxy is still needed for cross-domain usage. At least that is my understanding after reading this: http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/howto-proxy.html

Comment: I'm not confident that this will work but http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-site-xmlhttprequest/ seems to indicate that you can send access control headers that will allow your site to access the sites you specify using XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a proxy page on your server.

You can fetch the page server side, strip out what you need then write it out to a  proxy page that you can access via ajax, iframe or directly writing it out to page.

Comment: I just tried this. My server only allows php and the veetle page uses php as well (urls are formatted like this: veetle.com/index.php/channel/view#XXX). I think this is causing some problems, (it may be something else, not sure) because when I load a page through my proxy, it results in something like this: http://i.imgur.com/RwFeW.jpg